Is it actually safe to use spark.conf.set() function to update Spark properties?
Suppose I have a code:
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")

val partitionMode1 = spark.conf.get("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode")
print(s"Partitioning: $partitionMode1")

val partitionMode2 = spark.sparkContext.getConf.get("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode")
print(s"Partitioning: $partitionMode2")

This code will fail with error
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode
        at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.$anonfun$get$1(SparkConf.scala:245)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)

If I run my code I also don't see partitionOverwriteMode property in Spark UI Environment.
I know I could use
val spark = SparkSession.builder().config("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic").master("local").getOrCreate()

But the idea was to set conf after creating a session.
My question is it safe to update such property using spark.conf.set?

According to the docs, after the spark session is created, you cannot modify the SparkConf. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkConf.html

Once a SparkConf object is passed to Spark, it is cloned and can no longer be modified by the user. Spark does not support modifying the configuration at runtime.

